# How Does Skype Do The Android View At The Top?

Tags: android, android-widget, view, skype

I am trying to find the name of the built in widget that is used to make the static bar at the top of the Skype app for Android. Does anyone know? I think it adds easy button functionality.

Also, how within that bar they have a button to change the user's status.  It pops up a pretty bubble with an animation.  Is this something built into a library or custom?

Comment: Most likely they use the [action bar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html), although it is impossible to say for sure without seeing their code. You should be able to achieve a similar effect with it though.

Comment: I love you guys....super helpful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The action bar wasn't included until 3.0 as its the same app thats used for both tablets and smartphones, and on a tablet, the menu is still present, not shifted to where the action bar should be.

Its more likely they have each activities content in a scrollview, and a static layout pinned to the top of the page,

If you make your activities that will be using the top bar extend a base activity class that includes handlers for the static layout at the top of each page, and define the layout separately to be included in each activity's layout where it is required.

As for the bubble that animates out, it will be part of the layout but hidden, or not part of the layout, but inflated from xml pragmatically. i dont know what the exact animation is that makes it zoom in from the center though. The actual bubble will be another layout, wrapped in a FrameLayout so i sits nicely on top of the current activities layout.

Hope some of this was helpful

Answer (score 2):

Check out [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) for a library that lets you easily implement action bar on pre-Honeycomb devices.

Answer (score 1):

The static bar thar you are talking about is the action bar. It's included as standard in the version 3.0 of the API but you can also use libraries that provides you a very likely widget.

I use a modified version of [GreenDroid](https://github.com/cyrilmottier/GreenDroid) library... You can also install the [GreenDroid Catalog application](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.cyrilmottier.android.gdcatalog&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5jeXJpbG1vdHRpZXIuYW5kcm9pZC5nZGNhdGFsb2ciXQ..) from the Market to take a look.

Ah! of course you can change the color using styles!